# Dataframe append entire column if the header row is empty

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to merge the header column if it is empty with the nearby column.

For scenario-1, 
I need to merge column 3(Amount) and column 4(empty).

[image]

and I need the below result.

[image]

For scenario-2, 
I need to merge column 3(Empty) and column 4(Amount).

[image]

and I need the below result.

[image]

Any help would be really appreciated.

Note:
The row header is dynamic name. It is not static names as mentioned above. i.e., Header names would be anything.

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
   Amount Empty
0      10     €
1      20     €
2      30     €
3      40     €
```

---

using `np.where`

```
df['Amount'] = np.where(df['Amount'].astype(str) == '€', df['Amount'].astype(str) + ' ' + df['Empty'].astype(str), df['Empty'].astype(str) + ' ' +  df['Amount'].astype(str))

df.drop('Empty',1,inplace=True)
```

---

```
  Amount
0   € 10
1   € 20
2   € 30
3   € 40
```

Comment: please check my updated question.
The row header is dynamic. It is not static as mentioned above.

Comment: how are the headers getting generated...? please explain "dynamic"

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'' : ['€','€','€','€'],
                  'col0' : [50,100,25,90],
                  'col':1,
                  " ": [50, 100, 25, 90], 
                  "col2": ["€", "€", "€", "€"]}).rename(columns={' ':''})

print (df)
      col0  col      col2
0  €    50    1   50    €
1  €   100    1  100    €
2  €    25    1   25    €
3  €    90    1   90    €
```

You can check dtypes:

```
s = df.dtypes
print (s)
        object
col0     int64
col      int64
         int64
col2    object
dtype: object
```

If column name is empty string and dtype is object it means column is filled by currency, logic is then replace these empty strings to missing values and forward filling them, last replace empty columns names with numeric and replace column name by back filling:

```
m = (s == object) & (s.index == '')
a = s.index.to_series().mask(m).ffill().replace({'':np.nan}).bfill()
```

Output are same columns names for currency and next numeric columns:

```
df.columns = a
print (df)
   col0  col0  col col2 col2
0     €    50    1   50    €
1     €   100    1  100    €
2     €    25    1   25    €
3     €    90    1   90    €
```

Then use custom lambda function with `groupby` for join it together:

```
def f(x):
    if len(x.columns) == 2:
        if isinstance(x.iloc[0, 0], str):
            return x.iloc[:, 0] + ' ' + x.iloc[:, 1].astype(str)
        else:
            return x.iloc[:, 1] + ' ' + x.iloc[:, 0].astype(str)
    else:
        return x.iloc[:, 0]

df = df.groupby(df.columns, axis=1).apply(f)
print (df)

   col   col0   col2
0    1   € 50   € 50
1    1  € 100  € 100
2    1   € 25   € 25
3    1   € 90   € 90
```